# copying texture onto identical object

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, edit-mode

I have modeled a house and have already placed windows in different parts of the house. Each window consists of several objects. These windows (consisting of several objects) are identical and are only moved in their position. Now I want to texture only one window and all windows should get that texture. So if I change something on my "main"- or "master"- window/object all windows should get that change in texture as well. I don't want to have to texture each one individually.

Did I had to do something before copying or is it still possible? What I don't want is to texture it first and then copy it.

Feel free to contact me if you have any questions. Thank you in advance for the answers!

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are  Linked Objects the Uvs should be the same and if they share the same material also the texture, you can copy linked each

Comment: oh yes thats working! Thank you very much! So the soulution is to copy with alt D instead of shift D

Comment: If someone wants to see a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FkIf-R3IIxc

Answer (score 2):

If all your windows are identical you can link their UV maps and materials. Better yet, you can link all the object data if you want them to be perfect clones of one another.

You can do this by selecting all your windows (make sure the last one selected/highlighted in yellow is the one with the proper material data) then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> and selecting *Object Data*, *Materials*, and/or *Transfer UV Maps*.

Comment: for that I do need to combine them to one object (Ctr J) or don't I ?

Comment: No, this method works with distinct objects. If you Link object data, any changes you make to one (including changes to the mesh) will be automatically copied to all the other linked objects. If you only link material/UV data, only the material/UV data will be linked.

Comment: Give it a shot in an empty scene, add another object and link it to the default cube. Then, see what happens when you start editing either object.

Comment: So I do need to do it for every part of the window (frame, glass...). But Thank you for the answer. I learned something of it :)

Comment: ahhh ok thank you!! very helpfull!